# Is there a certification process for automated weather stations?

Tags: meteorology, measurements, instrumentation

I'm in the market for a new automated weather station and of course there's a glut of them on the internet. I mostly will be using the data for myself and my own amusement but do plan to submit measurements of temperature and wind speeds to the local NWS station for special weather events. Because of this, I want to make sure I'm using a station that is as accurate as can be.

I know the that the WMO has siting recommendations and those will be followed but I'm having trouble finding about **instrument certification or acceptability**. Is there such a thing or do I have to simply take the manufacturers at their word?

Comment: This sounds like a good question for law. I don't oppose this to staying here though.

Comment: Actually I was having the same doubts about certifications in weather stations. Did you find anything about it? Greetings from Argentina.

Comment: I haven't heard of anything, though not involved in the NOAA or related systems.  My suggestion lacking that would be to find accuracy and precision publications for your specific instrument at least, and check weather forums for threads discussing weather stations [like this one](https://stormtrack.org/community/threads/need-help-deciding-on-weather-station-anemometer.8237/)... might also opt for something a mesonet uses to have best hopes of a good mix of price and quality.